# What does mysql_escape_string() do?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

What does `mysql_escape_string()` do? I am updating a database. When I am using `$_POST('variable')`
it's not getting updated, but using it with `mysql_escape_string($_POST())` it works fine. I am calling this by ajax.

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string over mysql_escape_string. Better yet use PDO

Comment: mysql_escape_string has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3 try using mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 6):

[`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) is one of PHP mysql extension functions. It escapes a string provided as parameter for the function. *Escapes* means *prepends backslash (`\`) to special characters*.

- `mysql_escape_string` is designed to be used with [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function, to safely pass MySQL query parameters to the query. *Safely* means *with no possibility to affect and change the desired query behaviour*. Learn more by searching for "sql injection", e.g. [Secure Development Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Secure_Development_Guidelines#SQL_Injection) on MDN.
- *special characters* escaped with `mysql_escape_string` are: the null byte (`0`), newline (`\n`), carriage return (`\r`), backslash (`\`), single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`) and substiture (`SUB`, or `\032`). `%` and `_` are not being escaped with this function.
- `mysql_escape_string` has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. It should be replaced with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function, which in addition to escaping the string, takes into account the current character set of the connection.
- use of both `mysql_escape_string` and `mysql_real_escape_string` is discouraged with recommended alternatives of [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions.

In your case, the most probable reason why `$_POST('variable')` does not work, is that it contains one or more of the special characters, thus the MySQL query you're executing is unintentionally changed and broken. You're calling it with AJAX and if you're not processing the AJAX errors, you may not be able to see the error messages.